# Всегда ли нужно перезаписывать проксируемый объект в JS?

Tags: javascript, проксирование

Допустим, у нас есть объект:

```
let obj = { a: 'a', b: 'b' };
```

и мы создаём прокси-обёртку к нему:

```
let proxy = new Proxy(obj, {});
```

Будет ли это правильным использованием прокси или правильно **всегда** перезаписывать переменную?

```
obj = new Proxy(obj, {});
```

Если это не всегда правильно, то когда нужно перезаписывать, а когда создавать новую переменную для прокси?

Comment: Не вижу разницы. Не думаю, что тут есть "правильно" и "неправильно". Зависит от ваших целей и потребностей. Если исходный объект больше не нужен - можете перезаписывать. Если нужен, то лучше не перезаписывать.

Comment: а зачем его перезаписывать?

Comment: Очевидно нужно переписывать когда нужно и не нужно переписывать когда не нужно. Тут нет одного правильного ответа.